# What does the Re:ACT system do?

Tags: danganronpa-v3-killing-harmony

During the main story, outside of class trials, you can use the right analogue stick to pick a reaction.

[image]

I've tried using this at several points during the campaign, but it never seemed to *do* anything.

Does this actually serve any purpose?

Answer (score 1):

The system has no real purpose, its just there for a little bit of fluff. It lets you hear the protagonists voice, and gives you a small selection of different lines you can make them say whenever you want them to. It's a neat little feature, but is completely irrelevant to gameplay and only there if you choose to use it every now and then.